# Spring MVC: не отображаются изображения на странице

Tags: spring, mvc, css

Выкидывает вот такие ошибки:

> `WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ContactManager/images/fieldsetbg.gif] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'`
>
> `WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ContactManager/images/pagebg.gif] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'`

Вот кусок web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

собственно css:

```
body {
    font-family:        helv, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:          66%;
    color:              #1E1903;
    background:         #ffffff url(images/pagebg.gif) repeat-y center center;
    margin:             0;
    padding:            0;
}
```

где что не так? :(

Answer (score 1):

Тут все оч просто) 
Вам нужно указать папку для статики в servlet-context.xml

```
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Где resources папка со статическим контентом. Удачи!